# Why does my append dataframe in a function not work?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

This is a portion of my code:

```
df3      = pd.DataFrame(columns=["colA","colB"])

def someFunction(filePath,file,df): 
    df2      = pd.DataFrame(columns=["colA","colB"])
    df1      = pd.read_csv(filePath,header=0)
    var      = ["foo1","bar1"]

    df2['colA'] = ["foo2","bar2"]
    df2['colB'] = var

    df = df.append(df2)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    return df

for root, dirs, fileList in os.walk(someDir):
    for file in fileList:
        if <someCondition>:
            someFunction(filePath,file,df3)

print df3
```

On running the code, I don't see df2 getting appended to df3. Instead, the value of df3 within the function is the same as df3 and `empty dataframe` outside the function.

How do I consistently append df2 to df3 and get df3 to grow for every `file` processed?

Comment: In your example the `file` arg isn't used at all and the df2 is the same every time it's created - is this pertinent to the problem?

Comment: What happens if you concanate your Dataframes?   frames = [df1, df3], 
df3 = pd.concat(frames, axis = 1)

Comment: I use `file` in generating `df2['colA']`. I use `df2` as a local variable that creates a sub-dataframe for every `file` and then appends to `df3`

Comment: @hemanta: concat adds columns to the dataframe. I need to add rows

Comment: Axis = 0 does along row!

Comment: Tried this `frames = [df2,df]
 df = pd.concat(frames, axis = 0)`
Same result

Comment: You are not mutating the input but returning a new copy. You need to mutate or else call as `df3 = somefunction(..., df)`. Reassigning the result _inside a function_ won't work without a `global` keyword.

Comment: I got the code to work with `df3 = someFunction(filePath,file,df3)`. If you post your response as the answer, I will accept it.